# How to define Mongoose Schema?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have an application which generates the following JSON object/array which I want to save under my user in the database.

```
[ [ { _id: '5990e6d4fce2e705f8d74923',
      fname: 'test',
      lname: 'testerson1',
      username: 'email1@gmail.com',
      __v: 0,
      userid: '5990e6b9fce2e705f8d74922' },
    { _id: '5990e6e6fce2e705f8d74924',
      fname: 'test',
      lname: 'testerson2',
      username: 'email2@gmail.com',
      __v: 0,
      userid: '5990e6b9fce2e705f8d74922' } ],
  [ { _id: '5990e6f7fce2e705f8d74925',
      fname: 'test',
      lname: 'testerson3',
      username: 'email3@gmail.com',
      __v: 0,
      userid: '5990e6b9fce2e705f8d74922' },
    { _id: '5990e707fce2e705f8d74926',
      fname: 'test',
      lname: 'testerson4',
      username: 'email4@gmail.com',
      __v: 0,
      userid: '5990e6b9fce2e705f8d74922' } ] ]
```

What I am not sure of is how to define this in my model, what I have tried is:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    fname: String,
    lname: String,
    username: String,
    password: String,
    testers: [
        [
            {
                type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: "Tester"
            }
        ]
    ]
});
```

With this approach, I always get `MongooseError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[ { _id: '5990e6d4fce2e705f8d74923'` error message...which I am thinking is because the array I am trying to save does not have an ObjectId.

I have also tried removing the type and ref from the schema and leaving just the array, this works...my data JSON object/array is saved fine, but as I am still learning Mongo/Mongoose, I would like to know how to define this properly.

Thanks!

### EDIT:

```
router.post("/matchtesters", middleware.isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
    User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, user){
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            Tester.find({ "userid": req.user._id }, function(err, beans) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {           
                    console.log("TEST2: ", req.body);
                    console.log("TEST3: " + JSON.stringify(req.body));
                    user.testers.push(req.body);
                    user.save();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The double brackets `[ [ ... ] ]` around the content suggests that this is fact an "array of arrays". So when you say *"I have an application which generates the following JSON object/array"* then what exactly do you mean? Where is this coming from and how are you actually trying to "save/insert" the contents? Because this is actually more about how you are processing this input than the defined schema itself. What you need to be showing in your question is the code that actually acts with this source, rather than the schema.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks! I have updated my post to show the route which saves the array of arrays.